Which systems of formal logic do not admit vacuous truth for universal statements?
As I understand it there are systems of formal logic that do not admit vacuous truth for universal statements, what known systems of formal logic satisfy this constraint?
An example Kripke as I understand it does not admit vacuous truth for universals - but my understanding here might be wrong.
Links to original papers delineating these systems would be appreciated.

There're quite a few.  For instance, in relevance Logic the focus is on ensuring a stronger connection between antecedents and consequents than in classical logic. This helps avoid vacuous truths where universal quantifiers apply to empty domains or irrelevant conditions. Relevance logic adjusts the rules for conditionals and quantifiers to enforce these constraints. They may be viewed as a family of substructural or modal logics...

When "all A are B" entails "some A are B", i.e. any true universal conditional is non-vacuous, it is said that "all" has existential import. In particular, existential import follows from the so-called Boethius's thesis, (A → B) → ~(A → ~B), see Pizzi, Boethius' Thesis and Conditional Logic. Logics that accept  Boethius's thesis are called connexive logics, relevance logic is one of them.

On the relation to Aristotle's syllogistic, which is also usually interpreted to have existential import,  and its classical square of opposition, see Chatti-Schang, The Cube, the Square and the Problem of Existential Import.

We can split this question into two parts. Firstly, is it correct to represent a universal statement, "All S is P" as a conditional, "For any x, if x is S then x is P"? Secondly, are there conditionals that are not trivially true when the antecedent is false?
The answer to the second is that there are many such conditionals. The conditionals of relevance logics and connexive logics are examples. Also the conditionals from conditional logics such as Stalnaker's C2 logic and David Lewis' VC logic have that property.
It remains common to gloss "All S is P" as "For any x, if x is S then x is P", but it gives rise to some problems. For example, in the common relevance logics, if we use → to represent the conditional, then (∀x)(Sx → Px) is not trivially true in the event that there is no S, but also it is not trivially true in the event that everything is P. That is counterintuitive, since if everything is P then all S is P.
This can be fixed by introducing a different conditional, but it is unfortunate if we have to complicate relevance logic in this way. One of the main motivations behind relevance logic is to avoid the unintuitive features of the material conditional of classical logic. So if the relevant conditional → does not suffice, that suggests that relevance logic is not doing its job properly. There is some material on how this issue can be addressed in Graham Priest, An Introduction to Non-Classical Logic (Cambridge, Second edition, 2008) section 24.4, pp 541-543.
Another option is to use a free logic and distinguish between existence and potential existence or subsistence. We can then write (Πx)(Sx → Px) where Π is a quantifier that ranges over possible objects. This would not be trivially true in the event that there are no existing S.
